# React/Jest/MSW Wait for response throws errors using act()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs, msw

Currently, I'm learning how to unit test with React. However, I'd like to learn it with TypeScript, so the course does not cover most errors that occur with TS.

I have a simple testing function configured with Mock Service Worker (msw):

```
fit("sends username, email and password to backend after clicking the button", async () => {
  let requestBody;
  const server = setupServer(
    rest.post("/api/1.0/users", (req, res, ctx) => {
      requestBody = req.body;
      return res(ctx.status(200));
    })
  );
  server.listen();

  setupAll(); // Gets the elements on the page (like button)

  userEvent.click(button);

  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 250));

  expect(requestBody).toEqual({
    username: "LegacyUser",
    email: "legacy@user.com",
    password: "P455w0rd!",
  });
});
```

In theory, this 'works' (it shows as a Pass in the testing list), but above it errors occur, like:

```
console.error
  Warning: An update to SignUpPage inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
  When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
  act(() => {
    /* fire events that update state */
  });
  /* assert on the output */
```

So when I wrap `userEvent.click(button)` like `act(() => userEvent.click(button))`, it keeps showing this error message.

The click userEvent triggers an onSubmit handler:

```
const formSubmitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const { username, email, password } = formEntries;
  setIsApiInProgress(true);
  axios
    .post("/api/1.0/users", {
      username,
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        setIsSignUpSuccessfull(true);
        // console.log("OK", response.data);
        return response.data;
      }
      throw new Error(response.status.toString());
    })
    .catch(({ response }) => {
      console.log("CATCH", response);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsApiInProgress(false);
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, is there a way to wait for a resolved promise without using timeouts? It feels kind of hacky this way.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a Typescript related issue. It's this line `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 250));` that you need to wrap in `act` i.e. `await act(() => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 250)))`. You can read more up about it [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning).

Most relevant to your issue is this part:

> So the act warning from React is there to tell us that something
> happened to our component when we weren't expecting anything to
> happen. So you're supposed to wrap every interaction you make with
> your component in act to let React know that we expect our component
> to perform some updates and when you don't do that and there are
> updates, React will warn us that unexpected updates happened. This
> helps us avoid bugs like the one described above.
>
> Luckily for you and me, React automatically handles this for any of
> your code that's running within the React callstack (like click events
> where React calls into your event handler code which updates the
> component), but it cannot handle this for any code running outside of
> it's own callstack (like asynchronous code that runs as a result of a
> resolved promise you are managing or if you're using jest fake
> timers). With those kinds of situations you typically need to wrap
> that in act(...) or async act(...) yourself. BUT, React Testing
> Library has async utilities that are wrapped in act automatically!

Note how it specifically mentions how click events are handled for you (hence why wrapping the `userEvent` didn't solve the issue) **and** how promises you manage yourself are not handled (hence why we wrap it in act ourselves).

And you are correct that this is a hacky way. You can make use of RTL's async methods which are explained well in their [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor).

This:

```
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 250));

  expect(requestBody).toEqual({
    username: "LegacyUser",
    email: "legacy@user.com",
    password: "P455w0rd!",
  });
```

becomes something like this:

```
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(requestBody).toEqual({
    username: "LegacyUser",
    email: "legacy@user.com",
    password: "P455w0rd!",
  });
})
```